# PHP and MySQL date occurrence query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get some counts out of the MySQL database to be used in PHP. Seems like I should be able to get MySQL to output what the numbers I need without having to calculate it in PHP after the fact.

So this is what I'm looking to do. I'd like to count the occurrences of entries per month. So I have a database that looks like this.

```
DateTimeOriginal
2004:11:06 09:58:31
2004:11:08 10:00:25
2004:12:28 12:00:45
2005:03:02 05:00:15
2005:03:15 23:12:10
```

I'd like to write a query that outputs essentially this.

```
echo $row[0] . ":" . $row[1] . " = " . $row[2];

2004:11 = 2
2004:12 = 1
2005:03 = 2
```

I've tried a few things and can't see to wrap my brain around it. I'm fairly new to MySQL, but I know there are ways you can get MySQL to do some of the heavy lifting.

Comment: The best approach is probably to write a script/query that converts this custom date format into a MySQL date format, which then can be stored in a DATE field. This will not only improve the quality of your data but also simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the result columns (`$row[0]`, etc.) to be:

- Column 0: Year
- Column 1: Month (left-padded with zeros to length 2)
- Column 2: Count

In that case, this should work:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(DateTimeOriginal) AS TheYear,
  DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeOriginal, '%m') AS TheMonth
  COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
  YEAR(DateTimeOriginal),
  DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeOriginal, '%m')
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

---

**Addendum**: If two columns are OK (one for formatted year/month and one for the count), the query becomes a lot simpler.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeOriginal, '%m:%Y') AS YearMonth,
  COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeOriginal, '%m:%Y')
ORDER BY YearMonth
```

Many thanks to @GordonLinoff for pointing this out. It's a reminder that good advice is just as important as good code!

Comment: . . It seems easier to just use `date_format(DateTimeOriginal, '%Y:%m')` for the year and month.

Comment: I agree Gordon; that was my first thought but then I had an attack of being super-literal based on the request. I'll add your suggestion to the answer; it's good to give the OP some options.

Comment: That did it. Perfect. I'd use the `date_format(DateTimeOriginal, '%Y:%m')` instead like @GordonLinoff said for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Select year(a.DateTimeOriginal) as theYear, month(a.DateTimeOriginal) as theMonth,count(b.subDate) as theCount
From table a
    Inner Join (
        Select SUBSTR(DateTimeOriginal,7) as subDate) b
    On a.DateTimeOriginal = b.DateTimeOriginal
```